# Flutter run does not output error message or stack-trace ("[VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:")

Tags: dart, flutter

There is an exception throwing somewhere in the codebase of my flutter application.

However this is what the console output:

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
// (nothing, should be printing stack-trace or error message here)
```

[image: VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)]

Not having the stack-trace makes it very hard to find where this bug is coming from.

Does anyone know if it is normal that the stack-trace or the error message does not print?

Is there a mode in which I should run `flutter run` in order to see more information about the error being thrown?

Setup :

```
flutter: 0.2.8
running on an iphone device
```

Answer (score 2):

One insight to obtuse ios physical device / flutter errors is review the the physical device console and device logs. In my case, I'm using an iphone 6S trying to work on a camera app.

The logs are available via Xcode --> Window --> Devices and Simulators --> choose Devices, then select either "View Device Logs" or "Open Console" button. Select the button for "Errors and Faults" to make this a bit easier.

In my case I discovered an error in camera permissions that wasn't visible at all from my development environment.  The app just crashed, I had no clue why...  Then I found this in the log...

```
error   21:51:03.438135 -0700   tccd    Refusing TCCAccessRequest for service kTCCServiceCamera and client /var/containers/Bundle/Application/A817FC3E-F55D-46F5-9EF2-372E4FC90B1B/Runner.app[319] without NSCameraUsageDescription key
error   21:51:03.476854 -0700   Runner  This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
```

The fix for my camera dilemma on the iPhone is as follows:

- Find the Info.plist file (Location = flutter_image_picker/ios/Runner/Info.plist )
- Add the following key/string pair:

  `<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>`

  `<string>Camera used to take photos in support of the app.</string>`

All fixed!